# Python traceback error using urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am really confused, new to Python and I am working on a script that scrapes a website for products on Python27. I am trying to use urllib2 to do this and when I run the script it prints multiple traceback errors. Suggestions?

Script:

```
import urllib2, zlib, json

url='https://launches.endclothing.com/api/products'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header(':host','launches.endclothing.com');req.add_header(':method','GET');req.add_header(':path','/api/products');req.add_header(':scheme','https');req.add_header(':version','HTTP/1.1');req.add_header('accept','application/json, text/plain, */*');req.add_header('accept-encoding','gzip,deflate');req.add_header('accept-language','en-US,en;q=0.8');req.add_header('cache-control','max-age=0');req.add_header('cookie','__/');req.add_header('user-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36');
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
resp = zlib.decompress(bytes(bytearray(resp)),15+32)
data = json.loads(resp)
for product in data:
    for attrib in product.keys():
        print str(attrib)+' :: '+ str(product[attrib])
    print '\n'
```

Error(s):

```
C:\Users\Luke>py C:\Users\Luke\Documents\EndBot2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\EndBot2.py", line 5, in <module>
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1181, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1148, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error>
```

Comment: It seems to run fine here. No errors.

Comment: @jDo and you're on Python 2.7?

Comment: This happens with `HTTPS` sites and is an indicator that your computer's SSL software could be outdated, or that the server requested something you didn't have, like an SSL certificate. A lot of these problems go away if, instead of `urllib`, you use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), which boasts better across-the-board support for all of these issues and is industry standard.

Comment: @rated Yep, python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into issues with SSL configuration of your request. I'm sorry, but I won't correct your code, because we're in 2016, and there's a wonderful library that you should use instead: [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

So its usage is pretty simple:

```
>>> user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1'
>>> result = requests.get('https://launches.endclothing.com/api/products', headers={'user-agent': user_agent})
>>> result
<Response [200]>
>>> result.json()
[{u'name': u'Adidas Consortium x HighSnobiety Ultraboost', u'colour': u'Grey', u'id': 30, u'releaseDate': u'2016-04-09T00:01:00+0100', …
```

You'll notice that I changed the user-agent in the previous query to have it working, because weirdly enough, the website is refusing API access to `requests`:

```
>>> result = requests.get('https://launches.endclothing.com/api/products')
>>> result
<Response [403]>
>>> result.text
This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data.</p></div><div class="error-right"><h3>What can I do to resolve this?</h3><p>If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p><p>If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.
```

---

Otherwise, now that you've tried `requests` and your life has changed, you might still run into this issue again. As you might read from many places on internet, this is related to [SNI and outdated libraries](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2022) and you might get headaches trying to figure this out. My best advice would be for you to upgrade to Python3, as the problem is likely to be solved by installing a new vanilla version of python and the libs involved.

HTH

Comment: Note that simply switching to `requests` isn't enough: you can still get an SSL error. Usually, this is caused by [SNI issues](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2022) and is easily resolved by following the instructions in there.

Comment: yup I was about to raise that point, but I needed to make a bit more google-fu before posting ☺

Comment: Going to convert this to requests! So in doing this, the traceback errors will go away? @zmo

Comment: It *MIGHT*, but it's not 100%. The requests implementation is quite solid and flexible — it can adapt to many situation you'd have to otherwise handle manually with `urllib` — but because your issue is your low level libraries not handling properly some SSL cipher, it might fail. If it does, as I say in the second part of my answer, my advice to you is to update to python3… If then it does not work, then you should think about upgrading your operating system (or at least your ssl libs).

Comment: Alright, I'm going to assume it's something with my version of Python if requests doesn't work as I'm on Windows 10. Really appreciate the help, thanks for taking your time to teach me.

Comment: Well, if you're learning python, really, start with python3, and take python2 stuff only for "cultural" interest. Python2 has many little painful issues that are not anymore in Python3!